# How can I find a general term for this recursive sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm currently studying calculus and I came across this function:

the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, where $a_0=1$, and $a_n=\frac{6}{n}*a_{n-1}$. I'm trying to find a general term, so I listed the first four terms and got 1+6+18+36. I don't really see a pattern...what should I try next?

Comment: $$a_n = \frac{6}{n} a_{n-1} = \frac{6^2}{n(n-1)} a_{n-2} = \dotsb = \frac{6^n}{n!}, $$ *n'est-ce pas*?  Do you recognize the resulting series?

Comment: OH. Thank you!! @XanderHenderson

Comment: "I listed the first four terms and got 1+6+18+36": double check your computation.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with recurrence, it sometimes helps to not simplify your results, e.g., in this case, instead of calculating that $a_0=1,\ a_1=6,\ a_2=18,...$, you may write
$$a_0=1,\ a_1=\frac 6 1,\ a_2=\frac 6 2 \cdot \frac 6 1=\frac{6^2}{2\cdot1},\ a_3=\frac 6 3 \cdot \frac{6^2}{2\cdot 1}=\frac{6^3}{3\cdot2\cdot1},\ ...$$
By doing this, it's easier to notice that $a_n=\frac{6^n}{n!}$.